# Docker Build with ARG not passing

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Docker file:

```
# copy over system jboss configs
    ARG SYSTEM_TYPE
    COPY $SYSTEM_TYPE/AP/standalone.conf  $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf
    COPY $SYSTEM_TYPE/AP/standalone-ha-bob.xml  $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone-ha-bob.xml
```

Docker Command:

```
docker build --build-arg SERVER_TYPE=jbossconf/ENT-UAT/ -f /usr/etc/repos/docker-files/test-dockerfile-app -t appserver/test:1.0 .
```

Docker Build Result:

```
Step 15 : COPY $SYSTEM_TYPE/AP/standalone.conf $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf
lstat AP/standalone.conf: no such file or directory
```

The --build-arg does not appear to be passing to the dockerfile. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Looks like your $SYSTEM_TYPE isn't set

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Isn't that being set by --build-arg SYSTEM_TYPE=jbossconf/ENT-UAT/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your build args you are passing SERVER_TYPE and referencing  $SYSTEM_TYPE on your dockerfile, that should fix it!

Comment: Thanks Juan. That was a typo, sorry. I've fixed.